# webpack error angular wrapper for native lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have created a Service for an Angular App which is working fine as expected.
Its a Notification Service Wrapper for the package 'awesome-notifications'.
If I transfer the Service to the lib and use it from the lib i am getting kind of an import error its telling me something like constructor is not defined. Its referencing to the line :
'import AWN from "awesome-notifications"' which is the first line of the service.
its needed to create the notifier in the Service. Because its a Wrapper.
it seems like angular can not inject the service i wrote.
But if i am using it in an existing app it works, its really strange. does someone have experience with that ?

Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import AWN from 'awesome-notifications';

export interface NotificationRequestModel {
  message:string;
  title?:string;
}

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {

 notifier = new AWN();

 constructor() {
 }

 success(req:NotificationRequestModel) {
   this.notifier.success(req.message, {
   labels: { success: req?.title },
  })
 } etc..
```

**ERROR TypeError: awesome_notifications__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a constructor**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a build/bundle issue with webpack/typescript. Since one can't reproduce your setup you should provide an example with more information. Its probably the default import for your native library. I can only guess:

Do you have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` set in your ts config?